# AJAX auto complete with options for selecting query type

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-2.0

I want to use the AutoCompleteExtender control but i want to use it with a drop down list or radio buttons that let me select the search type. i.e. search by name or search by ID. Now the search bar is on the master page while the content is on a 'contained page' (i'm not sure of the correct terminology). Currently (i'm modifying existing code), the method that retrieves the list of items is a static method (and will only work as a static method for some reason) on the contained page. I can't see a way of reading the value of the drop down box from the master page, into the search method on the contained page. This seems like something that should be quite easy to do in concept.

Can anybody suggest a method for achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ContextKey property/functionality allows you to do that.

Comment: Thanks, that did the job. Just for anybody else out there here is a link to an example of how its done.

http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/AutoComplete_Textbox_Addtional_Parameters.aspx